# Impossible Backbone Zombies

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've been trying to debug my Backbone multi-page app for most of the day now to get rid of 'zombies', but unfortunately to no avail. Before today, I didn't even realize I have a *zombie problem*. What am I doing wrong?

This is my RegionManager:

```
  var regionManager = (function() {
    var currView = null;
    var rm = {};

    var closeView = function(view) {
      if (view && view.close) {
        view.close();
      }
    };

    var openView = function(view) {
      view.render();
      if (view.onShow) {
        view.onShow();
      }
    };

    rm.show = function(view) {
      closeView(currView);
      currView = view;
      openView(currView);
    };

    return rm;
  })();
```

This is my View cleaning up function:

```
  Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
    if (this.onClose) {
      this.onClose();
    }

    if (this.views) {
      _.invoke(this.views, 'close');
    }

    // Unbind any view's events.
    this.off();

    // Unbind any model and collection events that the view is bound to.
    if (this.model) {
      this.model.off(null, null, this);
    }

    if (this.collection) {
      this.collection.off(null, null, this);
    }

    // Clean up the HTML.
    this.$el.empty();
  };
```

I tried appending the View `el`s directly to the `body` and using `this.remove();` in the View clean-up function (instead of using a common `el: $('#content')` to which I am appending elements, then cleaning up by `this.$el.empty()`), but that didn't work either.

It might have something to do with my "global Events":

```
Backbone.Events.on('letterMouseDown', this.letterMouseDown, this);
```

But I take care of them with the onClose function:

```
onClose: function() {
  Backbone.Events.off('letterMouseDown');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I found the root for my problem.

mu is too short was right, with the `close()` method I wasn't removing the events bound directly to my `el` (which I tried to do by `this.off()` -  `this.$el.off()`/`this.undelegateEvents()` is the correct way). But for me, it only fixed the problem that events got called multiple times unnecessarily.

The reason I was plagued by 'zombie views' or unintended behavior was that I wasn't freeing up the memory in the View..

`this.remove()` only gets rid of the `el` and it's elements/events, but not the View's internal variables. To elaborate - in my View I have an array declared like so `this.array: []` and I didn't have it freed in the `onClose` function.

All I had to do was empty it in the `onClose` function or initially declare the array as `this.array: null` so on recurrent View renderings it would at least free the previous array (it still should be freed on the `onClose` method though, because the array/object is still going to sit in the memory until browsing away from the page).

It was **excruciating** to debug, because it's a crossword game (at least my code is hard to read there) and sometimes the words didn't match up, but I didn't know where the problem was coming from.

Lessons learned.

Comment: Something like `this.array = [ ];` should be fine, that should go away when `this` gets GC'd. However, there could be problems if you said `Backbone.View.extend({ array: [ ], ... })` as that `array` is attached to the prototype (and thus shared by all instances), it won't create a new array for each instance. BTW, I don't care about the un-accept, I'm more interested in getting at the real root of the problem, accidental reference sharing through the prototype is a fairly common source of problems in JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, wow. What you just said (about attaching the array to the prototype) is what I initially meant, but again - I thought I was doing the same thing which would've happened declaring the `array` "further away" (like in the `initialize` function). I was just declaring all the View's variables/properties at the top, so `this.x_variable` doesn't appear from nowhere. Fascinating how I keep getting things wrong. How'd you get the hang of all this? I want to know the ins and outs as well to avoid situations like this.

Comment: Prototypical inheritance (which JavaScript uses) takes some getting used to. Saying `a: [ ]` in the `Backbone.View.extend` call more or less attaches the array to the prototype but everything in the prototype is also accessible through `this` because the inheritance system follows the prototypes when looking for things, saying `this.a = [ ]` in `initialize` attaches it to the instance. Rule of thumb: don't attach mutable data to the prototype, assign mutable data directly to properties of `this`.

Answer (score 4):

One problem I see is that your `close` function never removes the event delegator from the view's `el`. A view's events are handled by using the delegator form of jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach a single event handler to the view's `el`. Your `close` does:

```
this.$el.empty();
```

but that only removes the content and any event handlers attached to that content, it does nothing at all to the handlers attached directly to `this.el`. Consider this minimal example:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'clicked'
    },
    clicked: function() {
        console.log('still here');
    }
});
var v = new V({ el: '#el' });
v.close();
```

After that, clicking on `#el` will throw a `'still here'` in the console even though you think that the view has been fully cleaned up. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aqdq7pwm/

Adding an [`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) call to your `close` should take care of this problem.

---

General advice:

1. Don't use the old-school [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) and [`off`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off) functions for events, use [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) and [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) instead. `listenTo` keeps track of the events on the listener so it is easier to remove them all later.
2. Simplify your `close` to just this:

   ```
   Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
     if(this.onClose)
       this.onClose();
     if(this.views)
       _.invoke(this.views, 'close');
     this.remove();
   };
   ```
3. Don't bind views to existing `el`s. Let the view create (and own) its own `el` and let the caller place that `el` into a container with the usual:

   ```
   var v = new View();
   container.append(v.render().el);
   ```

   pattern. If you must attach to an existing `el` then the view should override `remove` with a slightly modified version of the standard implementation:

   ```
   remove: function() {
     this.$el.empty();        // Instead of removing the element.
     this.undelegateEvents(); // Manually detach the event delegator.
     this.stopListening();
     return this;
   }
   ```

Comment: I agree with the `stopListening()` instead of `off()` and your analysis is correct. But why the advice to use `this.$el.empty(); this.undelegateEvents();` and not just `this.remove()` which will by default do `this.$el.remove();` which takes care of unregistering the event listeners on jQuery-side?

Comment: @try-catch-finally If you're binding a view to an existing `el` then you won't want to call `this.remove()` on it (without overriding `remove` of course) because you shouldn't be removing DOM nodes that you don't really own. Hence the advice to never bind views to existing elements; letting views create, own, and destroy their own nodes tends to work out better.

Comment: Right, so instead of ´this.off()' I had to call ´this.$el.off()´.. I thought that I was doing the same thing, because of the way it was specified here http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off (Note that calling model.off() will indeed remove all events on the model.). I don't have any models or collections where I have the events bound, so I can't use listenTo. I'm not really sure I fixed the problem, but I'll accept your answer as the correct one because you're probably right.

Comment: (1) `this.off()` works with Backbone events, `this.$el.off()` works with jQuery events. (2) `this.undelegateEvents()` should take care of the same things that `this.$el.off()` does.